# Browser connects to mysql database but Qt application can't except localhost

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

From any ip address and browser mysql database can be connected and operated without any problems. But from my Qt application database can only be accessed when hostname is set to setHostName("localhost") not when ip of the device is entered.

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
db.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
db.setDatabaseName("customdb");
db.setUserName("mojito");
db.setPassword("J0a1m8");
bool ok = db.open();
```

I get the error:

```
QSqlQuery::exec: database not open
```

When "127.0.0.1" is replaced with "localhost" connection is established. I checked and inserted relevant data to /etc/hosts but still issue occurs. So I can not type ip address and success with my Qt application code. Any suggestions ?

Comment: what error do you see when the connection fails?

Comment: QSqlQuery::exec: database not open

Comment: You should print the error after db.open() failed - currently you simply ignore the return value of db.open() for unknown reasons.

Comment: try [`db.lastError()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqldatabase.html#lastError). The error message you are seeing is presumably for attempting to use the database connection after it has failed to open rather than the cause of the database failing to open

Comment: "Can't connect to MySQL server on 127.0.0.1" Qt can't find anything but localhost

Comment: Since this parameter is directly passed to [mysql_real_connect()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-real-connect.html) I doubt it's a Qt problem